Error1: "'birthDate' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation",
I am getting above error in both for birthDate and age.
userSchema.virtual("age").get(function () {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const **birthDate **= this.dob;
    let **age **= currentDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

    const monthDiff = currentDate.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth(); 
    
    if (monthDiff < 0 || (monthDiff === 0 && currentDate.getDate() - birthDate.getDate() < 0)) { 
        age--;
    }
    return age;
});


This code will not work. First, you have asterisks in the code which are syntax errors (did you try to format some parts of the code bold? that doesn't work in code blocks). Second, this.dob is undefined in this context, see how does the "this" keyword work?. If this.dob is defined in the outer context, try to make the function an arrow function. Also could you edit your question and add the code which defines this.dob?
